# jquery: Selecting items with the same class as clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, svg, click

I have an SVG with large circles connected to small squares. The circles have classes A, B, C, etc. and the squares have corresponding classes, though some have more than one. I need a way to click on a circle and add a class to all elements that contain that class. Conversely, I also need to be able to click on a square, and have it add a class to all circles that match the array of classes. I'm sure this is easy, though I'm afraid I'm not experienced enough to have figured it out. Here's what I have so far.

```
// Click on circle to highlight boxes and connected lines
$('body').on('click','circle, ellipse, .program',function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var classArr = className.split(/\s+/);
    $("svg circle, svg path, svg ellipse").each(function() {
        var indvClass = $(this).attr('class');
        if ($.inArray(indvClass, classArr) !== -1 || $(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $(this).closest('.line').toggleClass('active');
        }
   })
});
```

EDIT --

Is it possible that it's firing before the SVG loads? I have updated my code, but it's not working in production.

```
$( '.mapsvg-wrap' ).find( 'circle, ellipse, path' ).click( function() {
        var isActive = $( this ).hasClass( 'active' );
        var classList = $( this ).attr( 'class' ).split( /\s+/ );
        $( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        if ( ! isActive ) {
            $.each( classList, function( index, className ) {
                if ( 'active' != className ) {
                    $( '.' + className ).addClass( 'active' );
                } else {
                    $( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                }
            } );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please include the markup as well.

Comment: "and add a class to all elements that contain that class" if your circles and squares contain multiple classes, how do you pick which class(es) to match on other circles and squares? Is this match an "All" or "Any" match?

Comment: @Sean It's a complex SVG so I didn't want to post the entire markup, but the circles only have one class, the squares have one or more. If you click on the A circle, all B squares should add a class. If you click on an ABC square, the A, B, and C circles should add a class.

Comment: Please see [mcve].  The concept of *minimal* markup, is *enough* to be able to help you.  Maybe an svg with 2 circles and 3 squares (1 for each circle and 1 for both) would suffice.

Comment: The first two paths should be active when the circle is clicked. Or if either of the first two paths are clicked, the circle should be active.     `<ellipse class="a" cx="467.9" cy="3860.8" rx="81.2" ry="81.2"/>
<path class="a" d=""/>
<path class="a b" d=""/>
<path class="b c" d=""/>`

Comment: Is it possible that the jquery is firing before the SVG is loaded? I have modified my code to what I think will work, but it's not working in production.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me exactly what you would like to achieve. But here I have an event listener on `<svg>`. 1) When clicked all "active" class names are removed. 2) for each of the class names for the clicked element, update the class list of the elements with that class name with "active".

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  // eventlistener for click
  document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // remove all class names "active"
    document.querySelectorAll(`svg .active`).forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('active'));
    // for each of the class names for the clicked element
    e.target.classList.forEach(cl => {
      // add "active" to all elements with that class name
      document.querySelectorAll(`svg .${cl}`).forEach(elm => elm.classList.add('active'));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <ellipse class="a" cx="2" cy="5" rx="2" ry="4"/>
  <ellipse class="b" cx="5" cy="5" rx="2" ry="4"/>
  <path class="a" d="M 0 0 L 0 1 L 1 1 L 1 0 Z"/>
  <path transform="translate(2 0)" class="a b" d="M 0 0 L 0 1 L 1 1 L 1 0 Z"/>
  <path transform="translate(4 0)" class="b c" d="M 0 0 L 0 1 L 1 1 L 1 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```